# Regexp won't match

Tags: regex, go

I am trying the following code

```
d := []byte("\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80J\x13\x80SQ\x80L\xe0\x80@\x92\x80L?\x80H\xe0")

r := regexp.MustCompile(`(\\x[0-9][0-9].*)+`)

fmt.Println(r.Match(d))
```

but it gives me false, although on an [online regex tester](https://regex-golang.appspot.com/assets/html/index.html) it works fine and matches the whole string

Comment: `\x01` is a escape sequence, the string will _not_ contain the literal characters but the byte 0x01.

Comment: so all the \ are to be replaced with 0 ? @tkausl

Comment: I edited the above code and changed `d` to a string under backticks and used MatchString instead and it worked. Can someone please explain that and also tell me how I can achieve the same using []byte ?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `\` in a string, it signals an escape character sequence. The string itself does not appear as `\x01...`, but instead, each of these chunks is converted into a *single character*.

That is to say that your regex is attempting to match the unprocessed string's value and not the actual string value stored in `d`.

I'm not sure how to improve your regular expression since it isn't clear to me what you expect it to match. Currently, it appears that you are attempting to validate that the byte array was instantiated using a specific method instead of by setting bytes to integers. If you can better articulate the aim of your regex, I may be able to provide assistance further.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the different kinds of [string literals in the Go documentation](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals).

You probably want to use the back-ticks (`) for a "raw_string_lit" in your first string.