# Matching serialized strings

Tags: regex, go

I am receiving this string `"\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80J\x13\x80SQ\x80L\xe0\x80@\x92\x80L?\x80H\xe0"`  from a function (which runs a `GET` command on a redis bitmap and gives me the serialized string)

But due to escape sequences I am having trouble matching this kind of pattern. Can some please tell me the regex sequence that will match this kind of string?

Comment: Isn't [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52116669/go-regexp-wont-match) the same question?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? As patterns go, `.*` will match your string, but I'm guessing you're looking for something more specific than that.

Comment: Which part should get captured exactly?

Comment: So I want to diffrentiate between normal strings returned by the ` GET` command for e.g. if there is a string pair stored in redis `SET key value` and on `GET key ` I get `value` similarly I get this kind \x01\x00\x00... of a string value when I run `GET ` on a bitmap key. So  I want to differentiate between the two to know on which data structure `GET` was called or to which data structure the key belongs to. @Adrian

Comment: I was trying something like this (\\x[0-9][0-9].*)+  so that the whole string matches @C4u

Comment: Since Redis is capable of storing binary data there is no way to know for sure if the string represents a bitmap, or if it's just a key that happens to store the string `"\x01\x00\x00\x00..."`.

Comment: My previously posted regex was crap. Sure you can capture "\" with anything behind. My testcase anyway captures all characters as (as already said above) this escaped sequence resolves to normal symbols.

Comment: Cross-post of [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/9bt0rj/go_regexp_string_wont_match/) question asked on `r/golang`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, I'd try to find out how to get that same data from Redis in its direct, binary, form (as `[]byte`); the rest would be way more simple then.

But to deal with this stuff in its present form,
I would first normalize the input string—replacing all those
backslash-escaped hex-encoded characters with their equivalent bytes.

This would allow easily searchig for the exact values of these
bytes—possibly using backslash-escaped hex-encoded characters
in the patterns:

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := "\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80J\x13\x80SQ\x80L\xe0\x80@\x92\x80L?\x80H\xe0"
    s, err := strconv.Unquote(`"` + s + `"`)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(strings.Index(s, "\x80SQ\x80L"))
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/JDQ5YQIqVpI).